# my 2000 vw eurovan makes a whining sound

Tags: vw

after I take my foot off of the brake and/or when I am going up a grade the whine or beeeeep sound .. usually I have driven a half hour or more sometimes sooner

Comment: Welcome to the site! We're going to need some more information in order to help you. Is the sound coming from the front of the vehicle? Does the sound change with throttle position or engine load? By usually, do you mean the sound does not occur when the engine is cold?

Comment: sound comes from the front most often when I release the brake .. stops when I accelerate .. no does not occur when engine is cold .. warmer it gets more it occurs

Comment: It might be sticky brake pads. Since it only happens when warm it will be more difficult to confirm. Does the brake pedal feel softer or squishier than it used to? I'm thinking air in the hydraulic lines is expanding, causing a well worn pad to stick against the brake disc.

Comment: I will have to check on that .. I didn't notice it